# Using Generics to create a factory with different parameters depending on T in TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript

Let's say we have a generic factory that can create different classes derived from `Fruit` like this:

```
function factory<T extends BaseClass>(obj: {new() : T})
{
    return new obj();
}
```

We can now create a new instance by calling `let yum = factory(Apple);`.
This is all fine and dandy, but what I want to do allow the derived class to *add* more parameters to `factory` so that I can call it like

`let redApple = factory(Apple, "red");`

but also like

`let clusterOfGrapes = factory(Grapes, 15);`

My question is now; is there a way of doing this? Preferably I'd want to be able to set the extra parameters somewhere, and somehow, in the derived class.

*I have tried to come up with something, but I've got nothing. I have not found anything on google either, but I'm, not 100% what to search for as I do not know what this is called.*